# My DataSpell can not display Latex formula properly

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, latex, dataspell

It is a Markdown cell in the Jupyter Notebook file. It is supposed to b a formula but it keeps its original format.

[image]

I have download TeXiFy plugins but it does not work. I wish it can display like this. This only happens in DataSpell but PyCharm performs good.

[image].

Comment: LaTex rendering support is on the way: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-58

Comment: off-topic: don't set complete words like "split" in math mode -- this will completely mess up the kerning. You can in particular see this by the horrible spacing after the "s" and the "l"

Comment: The latest EAP version has solved this problem.